# Understanding a step of the proof of the Hopf-Rinow's theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry

I am reading a proof of the Hopf-Rinow's theorem in [this](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Elee/Sven05.pdf) lecture notes and I am trying understand why

> $$d(\gamma(s_n),\gamma(s_m)) \leq |s_n - s_m|$$

on page $6$ instead of

> $$d(\gamma(s_n),\gamma(s_m)) = |s_n - s_m|$$

once that $\gamma$ is a normalized geodesic and the item $ii)$ of proposition $5$  of the lecture notes remains.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit speed geodesic $\gamma : I \to M$ does not always satisfies the equality $d(\gamma(t),\gamma(s)) = |t-s|$. For example, on the circle, $\gamma :t\in \mathbb{R} \mapsto e^{i t}\in\mathbb{S}^1$ is a unit speed geodesic, with $d(\gamma(2\pi),\gamma(0)) = 0 < |2\pi-0|$.

What is true is that, as $\gamma|_{[t,s]}$ is a path joining $\gamma(s)$ and $\gamma(t)$, $d(\gamma(t),\gamma(s))$ is less that the length of $\gamma|_{[t,s]}$, which is exactly $|t-s|$ if $\gamma$ is of unit speed.